# variables into JSON datatype

Tags: json, postgresql, psql

can i insert a variable in a JSON datatype in postgreSQL - if yes how?

I have a procedure with JSON datatype and I want to insert the variables into the JSON.

as I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Please add more details about data and append JSON filed for getting better advise

Answer (score 0):

So the variables doesn't have to be declared i JSON, rather just extract through the JSON using ->> operator.
example -

```json
execute format('INSERT INTO "transactions_packs"."simple_basic_geographical_measurements_packs" ("latitude") VALUES (%s), "_meta_measurements_packs"->>'latitude';
```